# Putting utf-8 dict in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've got a little FAQ.conf file containing dict structure that I'm importing with ast to Django. Question and Answer contain utf-8 chars and html markup.

```
{
'1': {'question':'','answer':''},
'2': {},
'3': {},
}
```

So I use ast to import it:

```
with open(os.path.join(FS_ROOT, FAQ_FILE)) as q: FAQ = ast.literal_eval(q.read())
```

After putting it into my view context and using filter {{ FAQ|safe }}
I receive:

```
{'1': {'answer': 'zewn\xc4\x99trznych mog\xc4\x85 si\xc4\x99 do\xc4\x87 osoby. W szczeg\xc3\xb3lno\xc5\x9bci takie, kt\xc3\xb3rych. ...}
```

What should I do to get proper output in my templates?

Comment: it look like json.y cant u convert it to json object

Comment: I'm passing it to context like 'FAQ':FAQ. Should I use simplejson somehow?

Because what 'FAQ':simplejson.loads(FAQ) with just putting {{FAQ|safe}} into html does is:

{"1": {"answer": "zewn\u0119trznych mog\u0105 si\u0119 dopisywa\u0107 osoby. W szczeg\u00f3lno\u015bci takie, kt\u00f3rych...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Python 2, the problem is that you are reading the file as a byte string and not a Unicode string. I believe `ast` handles utf-8 fine, so you can simply do:

```
with open(os.path.join(FS_ROOT, FAQ_FILE)) as q: FAQ = ast.literal_eval(q.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Or use `codecs.open` to open the file with the correct encoding.

---

If `ast` doesn't like your Unicode characters, you can call `decode()` on the strings before passing them to Django.

---

If you are using Python 3, the problem is probably that the encoding *isn't* utf-8, in which case using `codecs` as above should work, provided you use the correct encoding.

Comment: With decode it gives the result like in the comment before:
{"1": {"answer": "zewn\u0119trznych mog\u0105 si\u0119 dopisywa\u0107 osoby. W szczeg\u00f3lno\u015bci takie, kt\u00f3rych...}

Also it doesn't let me iterate over it like this:
`         {% with FAQ|safe  as faq%}
             {% for key, value in faq.items %}
                {{value}}
           {% endfor %}
         {% endwith %}`

It puts nothing in html. I can only see {{faq}} or {{FAQ|safe}}.

Python 2.7.3

Comment: Actually your answer helped me. Also it didn't want to render in FULL size. But iterating over it and using |safe filter only on the right elements (not on whole dict) made it work.

Thank you.